# Media color RGB de un círculo

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy intentando sacar la **media** del color **RGB** de cada uno de los 96 círculos que tengo con **OpenCV**. De cada círculo tengo la coordenada del centro y su radio, con eso hago:

```
mask = np.zeros(color_img.shape, np.uint8) 
cv2.circle(mask,(key[0][0],key[0][1]),radio,255,thickn‌​ess=-1)
masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(color_img, color_img, mask=mask)
mean = cv2.mean(color_img, mask=masked_data)
print(mean)
```

`key[0][0]` es la coordenada X del centro del círculo.
`key[0][1]` es la coordenada Y del centro del círculo.

Me devuelve este error:

> error: (-215) (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type() == CV_8SC1) in function binary_op

Por lo que me comentan es como yo lo estoy haciendo pero no se como hacerlo funcionar...